# How to get cart subtotal inside WC_Shipping_Method calculate_shipping() method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, calculation, shipping-method

So I was trying to create a woocommerce shipping method that takes the cart subtotal and charges a user-defined percentage of the cart subtotal as a shipping fee. As a first step towards this goal, ehat I did was basically like this

```
class Subtotal_Percentage_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
    // to store percentage
    private $percentage_rate
    // constructor that handles settings
    // here is where i start calculation
    public function calculate_shipping($packages = array()) {
        $cost = $this->percentage_rate * 1000;
        add_rate(array(
            'id' => $this->id,
            'label' => $this->title,
            'cost' => $cost
        ));
    }
}
```

This one works. However, it doesn't work when I change the calculate_shipping method to use the cart subtotal in the calculation like this

```
public function calculate_shipping($packages = array()) {
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    $cost = $subtotal * $this->percentage_rate / 100;
    add_rate(array(
        'id' => $this->id,
        'label' => $this->title,
        'cost' => $cost
    ));
}
```

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is related to shipping packages (as cart items can be splitted (divided) into multiple shipping packages), you need to use instead the variable `$packages` argument included in `calculate_shipping()` method.

So your code will be lightly different without using `WC_Cart` Object methods:

```
public function calculate_shipping( $packages = array() ) {
    $total = $total_tax = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through shipping packages
    foreach( $packages as $key => $package ){
            // Loop through cart items for this package
        foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ){
            $total      += $item['total']; // Item subtotal discounted
            $total_tax  += $item['total_tax']; // Item subtotal tax discounted
        }
    }

    add_rate( array(
        'id'       => $this->id,
        'label'    => $this->title,
        'cost'     => $total * $this->percentage_rate / 100,
        // 'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
    ) );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

**Note:** Here the calculation is made on **cart items subtotal after discount** (without taxes). You can add easily add make it on **cart items subtotal after discount with taxes**, replacing:

```
'cost'     => $total * $this->percentage_rate / 100,
```

by:

```
'cost'     => ($total + $total_tax) * $this->percentage_rate / 100,
```

> You can see how are made the shipping packages looking to: 
> [`WC_Cart` `get_shipping_packages()` method source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.3/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1320-L1357)

> If you want to handle also shipping classes and more, check: 
>  [`WC_Shipping_Flat_Rate` `calculate_shipping()` method source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.3/includes/shipping/flat-rate/class-wc-shipping-flat-rate.php#L141-L217).

Comment: does your code get the price before or after discount? what i wanted to do is get the price after discount.